# Qual o gênero de "COVID(-19)" e "SARS-CoV-2"?

Tags: gênero

O gênero da palavra informal *corona* é fácil, já que ela vem de *coronavírus*, que é masculino por *vírus* ser masculino; então, *corona* é masculino. Mas o gênero de *COVID-19* não é óbvio, nem do nome oficial do vírus *SARS-CoV-2*.

Então pergunto: qual o gênero de *COVID(-19)* e de *SARS-CoV-2*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do [Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) consta que **SARS-CoV-2 é masculino e COVID-19 é feminino**.

---

Quando a palavra é totalmente estranha à evolução natural da língua — e.g. siglas e nomes científicos —, a regra geral é que o gênero é aquele do especificador subentendido (o que determino por inspeção, por ora):

- O [protozoário] [*Toxoplasma gondii*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxoplasma_gondii).
- A [bactéria] [*Escherichia coli*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escherichia_coli).
- A [enzima] [RuBisCO](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuBisCO).
- O [mosquito] [*Aedes aegypti*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aedes_aegypti).

No caso que você traz, tende-se a tratar **[COVID-19](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19) como a doença**, pois vem de *Coronavirus Disease 2019*, e **[SARS-CoV-2](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronav%C3%ADrus_da_s%C3%ADndrome_respirat%C3%B3ria_aguda_grave_2) como o vírus**, pois vem de *Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2*. Logo,

- O [vírus] SARS-CoV-2 tem ARN como material genético.
- A [doença] COVID-19 causa mais problemas que a gripe.

Porém, como em alguns casos pode haver múltiplos especificadores comuns, o gênero pode mudar dependendo do contexto ou do especificador que o autor da frase prefere. Por exemplo,

- Ele estacionou seu [carro] Chevrolet ao lado do hidrante!
- Em geral, a [marca] Toyota se saiu melhor que a [marca] Chevrolet no quesito eficiência energética.

Comment: É exatamente isso, embora as pessoas confundam um pouco o gênero na hora de falar.  Vale a pena citar que por vezes, o uso popular errôneo se difunde tanto, que consagra uma determinada forma.  Foi o caso do dengue, uma doença que aprendi na faculdade como sendo do gênero masculino ("o dengue") e que, após as epidemias da última década do século passado, sofreu mudança de gênero ("a dengue") devido ao uso popular.  Com 99% da população dizendo "a dengue", os dicionários passaram a classificá-la como substantivo feminino, e alguns poucos dicionários aceitam-na substantivo de dois gêneros.

Comment: @Centaurus, exatamente. Não sei se não estará a acontecer isso mesmo no caso do covid aqui em Portugal. Não sei se neste caso é confusão. Eu sei que oficialmente é *a covid*, o pessoal da Direção Geral de Saúde na televisão diz sempre *a covid*, mas acho que eu e pessoas com quem falo tendemos a dizer *o covid*; sei lá, soa melhor...

Comment: @Jacinto  O "certo" seria "a" COVID porque o D é "disease".  Mas ouço muitas vezes "o COVID" porque o interlocutor pensa em vírus, que é masculino.  Já em inglês, não há esse problema, é tudo gênero neutro.

Comment: Interessante, e eu nunca havia pensado a respeito, seria saber porque a maioria das doenças que terminam em "e" são do gênero feminino (coqueluche, bronquite, amiloidose, cirrose, gastrite, aterosclerose, etc) e porque muitas doenças que terminam em "a" são do gênero masculino (cólera, enfizema, aneurisma, mixoma, glaucoma, linfoma, etc.)

Comment: @Centaurus Cólera é feminino, não? Pelo menos sobre doenças com sufixo "oma" dá pra dizer que são tumores, "ites" são inflamações. Mas quanto a algumas realmente acho que não dá pra dizer muito, especialmente enfizema e aneurisma.

Comment: Não, os leigos podem achar que é feminino e os dicionários até citam como substantivo de dois gêneros, mas no meio médico nós usamos apenas no masculino.  Lembra da obra de Garcia Marquez "O amor nos tempos **do** cólera"?

Comment: Refiro-me à doença, não à ira ou raiva.

Comment: @Centaurus, eu sei dessa justificação, simplesmente não acho a lógica suficientemente forte para me obrigar a a aceitar. *Covid* não é abreviação de *doença do*...; isso seria *docov* ou coisa assim. Portanto passa a ser mais uma palavra com outra qualquer, e não vejo que o seu género seja logicamente determinado por qualquer tradução que façamos do original (até porque eu posso traduzir *the disease* por *o mal*). E já há precedentes. *Light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation* deu-nos ***o** laser*, e *radio detection and ranging* deu-nos ***o** radar*.

Comment: @Jacinto, a palavra *COVID-19* vem de *coronavirus disease* + (20)19. O Houaiss interpretou como *mal do coronavírus*, enquanto o Priberam como doença. Então realmente tens um bom ponto. Acho que por ora vai conforme a opinião do falante, mas depois provavelmente será feminino, porquanto é a mais usada.

Comment: @LoremIpsum, como doença, o nome científico é *cholera-morbus*, e, como o gênero é definido pela palavra final e *morbus* é masculino (lat. *-us* > pt. *-o*), a doença é o cólera. Talvez o *cólera* seja redução de *cólera-morbo*  ¯\\_(º-º)_/¯.